# How to pass argument to docker image having python script

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to make a classification docker container, but here i am putting a short code.
The issue is that docker is not able to take the image folder as input.
Here is Dockerfile

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.6.0-cuda10.1-cudnn7-runtime
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    # we have found python3.7 in base docker
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    build-essential \
    && \
    apt-get clean && \
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /workspace
COPY inference.py /workspace
ENTRYPOINT  ["python", "inference.py"]
```

Here is `inference.py` file

```
from glob import glob
import torch
import os

print(os.getcwd())
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-i", '--input_folder',  required=True)    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    #load data
    images = sorted(glob("{}/*.nii.gz".format(args.input_folder)))
    data_dicts = [
                {"image": image_name}
                for image_name in images
            ]
    print('number of images',len(data_dicts))
    print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Using build command i build docker image
`docker build -t test .`
This is how i am running
`docker run --gpus all test -i=images`

The folder `images` is in current directoy. What i am expecting to print the number of images.
When i run the image using `docker run --gpus all test -i images` it print following

```
/workspace
number of images 0
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the container access to your images folder by mapping it into the container filesystem as a volume. You do that using the `-v` option on the `docker run` command.

If your images are in the `images` folder on your computer and the container expects them in the `/workspace/images` folder, you'd map it like this

```
docker run --gpus all -v $(pwd)/images:/workspace/images test -i images
```

Comment: still it print `number of images 0`

Comment: but if i do `python3 inference.py -i images` without docker, it shows me number of images

Comment: this helps `docker run  --gpus all -v $PWD/images:/workspace/images test -i images`

Comment: Yes, sorry. The host path needs to be absolute.